# Surface wpf : move an ellipse wherever in the window

Tags: wpf, pixelsense

I want to create an ellipse who move unpredictable wherever in the window and know in the same time his postion. Like a ball who are going everywhere in the surface and if his meet a corner he changes his direction.

Thanks for your help.
Sorry if my explication is not specific

Comment: Are you asking for how to draw an ellipse, change position of an ellipse or how to do edge detection?

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer as you do not provide enough specific information on what you need to know (edge detection, positioning, ...). A general hint: WPF supports two way binding. That will allow communicate values back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

look at the "paddleball" sample in the Surface SDK.  it does exactly what you describe